# Extract text between two html tags

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to retrieve the text between the tags  and . I am working with SunOS.

```
       [SESSIONID=9sfhksfksafa,LOGINID=1,CLIENTIP=1.22.34.5,REMOTEADDRESS=1.22.34.5] 2017-06-01T18:09:20  INFO transaction - Soap Outbound message: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://org.inq"><Id>Id1</Id><header><userID>321</userID><organization>abc</organization><countryCode>CA</countryCode><languageCode>en</languageCode><userLocation>internet</userLocation>
       <timestamp>2017-06-01T18:09:20.974-04:00</timestamp><channel>Mobile</channel>
```

I tried the following options but did not help:

```
      sed -e 's/<Id>\(.*\)</Id>/\1/'
      sed -n '/<Id>/,/<\/Id>/p' test1.txt > test2.txt
```

Any suggestions would help me very much.

Comment: There are countless questions and answers already on the site which will tell you how to do this (and the good ones will mention why you shouldn't).

Answer (score 3):

if grep supports PCRE

```
grep -Po '<Id>\K[^<]*'
```

otherwise

```
perl -ne 'print "$_\n" for /<Id>\K[^<]*/g'
```

another option bash

```
while IFS=\> read -d \< tag value; do echo "$tag $value"; done
```

or if variable contains string

```
var='<Id>2017-06-01T18:09:20.974-04:00</Id>'
var=${var#*<Id>}   #remove prefix
var=${var%</Id>*}  #remove suffix
echo "$var"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!! But still it does not extract the text between tags.

Comment: I am trying not to unzip a .Z file using zcat and then pipe sed with the result:
zcat file1.Z | sed -n '/DserviceID/s/<\/serviceID.*//p'. But I get empty result but there is content inside serviceID tag.

Comment: can you give a fragment of file ? and what you tried , please.